# How can I reproduce this magnification effect for my own screen shots?

Tags: macos, applications, photos, screen-capture

Does anyone know how to make the great-looking magnifying glass, shown in Apple's image, shown below? I really like the shadow! I'd love to know what software Apple uses for this.

[image]

Comment: In Preview you can now add shadowed magnification.  I think this was new in El Capitain.  But it is not the same shadow.  My guess is that effect is produced in Quartz Composer.

Comment: I see *un*shadowed magnification in Preview. I also don't see a way to save it. Am I missing something?

Comment: I figured out how to save it. Not sure what I was doing wrong, but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

In Preview you can now add shadowed magnification. I think this was new in El Capitain. But it is not the *same* shadow. My guess is that effect is produced in Quartz Composer (if they want to "eat their own dog food").

See interface:

[image: Preview interface]

Comment: Thanks, I've started using that until I find the more attractive one Apple uses.